# How to compare executed function output correctly?

Tags: javascript, function

So what im trying to do in general is -> get a moment when user scrolls up really fast on mobile device -> some text executed in console (for example)

What I have is 2 simple functions:

```
//calculate scroll speed
var mobileScroll = (function(){
    var last_position, new_position, timer, delta, delay = 50; 
    function clear() {
        last_position = null;
        delta = 0;
    }
    
    clear();
    return function(){
        new_position = window.scrollY;
        if ( last_position !== null ){
            delta = new_position -  last_position;
        }
        last_position = new_position;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(clear, delay);
        return delta;
    };
 })();
```

Then I'm trying to compare the outputted value with some static number like this:

```
var scrolledFast = function scrolledFast(e) {
   console.log("scroll: " + mobileScroll());//works fine
   console.log(mobileScroll());//always 0
   //if statement does not work
   if(document.body.classList.contains('on-mobile-device') && mobileScroll() < -200 ){    
      console.log('Scrolled up fast enough');   
   }
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', scrolledFast);
```

The problem is that I don't understand why I can get the outputted value like this:

```
console.log("scroll speed: " + mobileScroll()); // I see "scroll: -100" or some other value
```

But when I'm trying to get something like:

```
console.log(mobileScroll());
//or
var mobScrollSpeed = mobileScroll();
console.log(mobScrollSpeed);
```

it is always 0...

Comment: Your delay is set to 50ms. So it resets the delta to 0 really fast. Try setting the delay to 5000 and see if the output is still 0.

Comment: Why does the mobile scroll need to reset at all?